# Managing multiple layouts using Zend_Layout?

Tags: zend-framework, layout

I am trying to implement a templating sytem in zend framework.

I basically use to put all the partials files and template variation in one file, but as the templates are increasing this is beign highly unmanageable.

for example

```
/application/layout/script/template1partial-banner.phtml
/application/layout/script/template1partial-footer.phtml
/application/layout/script/template1variation1.phtml
/application/layout/script/template1variation2.phtml
/application/layout/script/template2variation1.phtml
/application/layout/script/template2variation2.phtml
```

You can see, how unmanageable this is
so i want to manage it under this structure

```
/application/layout/script/template1/partial/banner.phtml
/application/layout/script/template1/partial/footer.phtml
/application/layout/script/template1/variation/1.phtml
/application/layout/script/template1/variation/2.phtml

/application/layout/script/template2/partial/banner.phtml
/application/layout/script/template2/partial/footer.phtml
/application/layout/script/template2/variation/1.phtml
/application/layout/script/template2/variation/2.phtml
```

Well defining the partials is not a problem, you can just use `$this -> render($this -> getTemplateName()."/partials/banner.phtml");`

Its the variations, that is main problem
I used `$this -> _helper -> layout -> setLayout('template1variation1');` before, but for the new thing I can't use it, now.

How can i do something this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also define a complete path in your `layout` function.

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('template1/partial/banner');
```

One Other way to do this task is to disable layout for your current action and then render it to any phtml file. For example first `disable` layout for current action

```
   $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

Then just render to any html file like this

```
      $this->render("complete path to your phmtl file");
```